# Creating view entity which uses column alias instead of actual column name throws exception

Tags: hibernate, jpa, view, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa

Below is the view created using three tables with alias names used from all three tables (column names are same in two tables that's why i am using alias name instead of actual column name )

```
create view SAMPLE_VIEW1 as
select w_id,collab_key,TAB3.START_TIME as W_DATE,batch_step_execution.STEP_NAME AS CURRENTSTEP ,batch_step_execution.start_time as STEPTIME ,TAB3.EXIT_CODE as JOB_STATUS from batch_step_execution inner join
(select * from SAMPLE_ID_MAPPING
inner join
(select batch_job_execution.job_execution_id,batch_job_execution.job_instance_id ,batch_job_execution.START_TIME ,batch_job_execution.EXIT_CODE
from batch_job_execution where start_time in (select max(start_time) 
FROM batch_job_execution where job_instance_id in (select job_id from SAMPLE_ID_MAPPING) group by job_instance_id)) TAB2
on SAMPLE_ID_MAPPING.job_id =  TAB2.job_instance_id) TAB3
on batch_step_execution.job_execution_id = TAB3.job_execution_id
where batch_step_execution.start_time = (select max(start_time) 
from batch_step_execution where batch_step_execution.job_execution_id = TAB3.job_execution_id)
```

Here is the corresponding jpa entity for the above view.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SAMPLE_VIEW1")
public class RpxWorkflowListViewEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "W_ID")
    private String workflowId;
    @Column(name = "COLLAB_KEY")
    private String collaborationKey;
    @Column(name = "W_DATE")
    private Date workflowDate;
    @Column(name = "CURRENTSTEP")
    private String currentStep;
    @Column(name = "STEPTIME")
    private Date stepTime;
    @Column(name = "JOB_STATUS")
    private String jobStatus;
/* getters and settters 
}
```

Now ,when i try to use the above entity ,i get the following error .

```
nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property startTime found for type SAMPLE_VIEW1 !]
```

**I believe jpa is trying to use actual column name instead of alias name ,is there a way to force jpa to use alias name instead of actual column name ?**

Comment: The exception complains about a property named `startTime`, and there is no such property in what you posted. What does the exception really complain about? Post the complete stack trace of the exception. My guess is that you have a findByStartTime() repository method somewhere.

Comment: Yes ,you are correct ,somewhere in one of the controller ,i am using startTime instead of STEPTIME  .